Missing data imputation in longitudinal data in R
I have very big dataset (around 10 million rows) with repeated measures of around 500 000 individuals, irregularly spaced through time. My final goal is to do IPTW and fit a weighted cox regression with time varying covariates and competing risks. (Compare effect of some medications on stroke risk with competing risk of death). I have several variables with large percentages of missing data (ranging from 0 to 50% missing), some continuous some binary some ordinal.
I want to impute this data before the analysis, since a complete case analysis would be biased but also ipw package as far as I know does not allow for missing data, in the confounders.
The thing is that since we have repeated measures these are clustered data, and therefore we need 2 level imputation.
I was thinking of trying 2 level multiple imputation with predictive mean matching using the mice package in R.
My questions are:

Is this a valid approach?
Is this approach computationally doable in a high end desktop, with let's say 5 imputations and maybe 10 iterations?
Are there other more valid and/or more efficient approaches?

And most importantly is the implementation described somewhere in a more begginer friendly manner, maybe a good tutorial or example?
P.S: So far I have done PMM only in SPSS and it was suprisingly easy to implement. Ideally, I would want a method with minimal data manipulation, but I do not know if this is possible.

I have similar data with similar needs. I chose for a multilevel imputation as well. Although it is a rather new technique, the methods for imputing variables (certainly categorical variables) are limited.
To decide which method you need, you have to know your data.

Make a distinction between level 1 and level 2 variables --> They should be imputed differently! (To those who are not familiar with these terms: you have to make a distinction between variables that change value over time/repeated measures (i.e. level 1 variables like often bmi, hypertension, ...) and variables that stay constant over time/repeated measures (i.e. level 2 variables such as sex, birth year, ...). In van Buuren's book (see below), the possible methods for each case/level variable are outlined very nicely.

Know the type of each variable: for continuous variables, 2l.norm or 2l.pmm is often used, for binary variables 2l.bin is rather used.


Next, you have to specify your predictor matrix carefully. In ordinary imputation, this is just 0 (if you don't use it for imputing other variables) and 1 (if you do use it for imputing other variables). Now that you use multilevel imputation, you have more options:

0 is still to keep a variable out of the imputation model.

1 is now usually used for level 2 variables.

2, 3 and 4 are used for level 1 variables using respectively random intercept and slope (2), random intercept and cluster means (3) and random intercept and slope, and cluster means (4). Including cluster means seemed to have a beneficial effect in some simulations as for example van Buuren en Vink pointed out. You can thus choose to incorporate different combinations of random intercepts/slopes and/or cluster means. It has been shown that there is no big difference between specifying 2, 3 or 4 for a level 1 variable. However, option 4 can make the model heavier and not necessarily better, whereas option 2 does not incorporate cluster means, so option 3 is often advised!

The most important and also a new one: -2, this is to denote the cluster variable.


!! Caution !!: This cluster variable needs to be a numerical variable! If you have a character or factor variable denoting the ID's of repeating measures for example, you need to convert this. This is something that yet needs to be fixed.
I based these things mainly on books/vignettes by Stef van Buuren, Gerko Vink and Martijn Heymans. Here are a few links that helped me with understanding the basics:
van Buuren
Heymans
Vink
Now, about your question of computationally feasibility: this might be the biggest problem. Since the data is very big and the algorithms are very heavy, I encountered (and am still encountering) problems with RAM memory. Also the computation time is very long, even for a small subset. This can be helped by using split-samples (just processing chunks at a time instead of everything together) and using parallel computations (for example using the parallel package). Using the chunks can diminish the efficiency very slightly since you are not using 100% of the information for your imputations anymore now, but the time won can be a big gain.
I advise to use a computer with as much RAM as possible and as much cores as possible to have an optimal workflow.

Thank you for this very helpful reply! I will be using 2l.pmm from the miceadds package. Propably using parallel processing.
How about predictor variables that are not always constant but have very small and rare within-cluster variation. These can be for example education level. It is very rare for older individuals to increase their education level however it is possible. Or e.g chronic comorbidities like cancer that may be absent in the begining appear later but stay as present after that. Should these be considered level 1 or can I include them as level 2 since the change is rare?

Yes, 2l.pmm is a good choice for the categorical ones. For the variables that change, you have to consider them as level 1, R will complain if there is even just 1 value that changes when you put them as level 2 (I tried the same thing, but it did not work out). Good luck!

Thanks! In test samples, I got no errors even when I put everything as level 2, but since it is the most correct way, I will keep only constant variables as level 2  and everything else I set to level 1 with random intercept and cluster means. Density plots and convergence seem fine. BTW have you got any idea if and how the function mice::futuremice for parallel processing can be used with methods from miceadds ? It would be an easy solution to some problems I have with the parallel package.

Nice to hear! Sorry, I have no experience in doing that :/ I used the parallel package either way to incorporate mice and miceadds, maybe I can however help with the problems form the parallel package?

I had some problem in combining the results of the parallel processing into a mids object, however, Futuremice was updated and now arguement package = "miceadds" should be added to the futuremice() function, in order to use 2l.pmm with parallel processing, without the need for foreach().
